# QGIS Model Designer adding fields with drop down attributes

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, qgis-modeler

Im trying to automate some processes at work, one of them in importing a shapefile... then adding some fields. I want some of these fields to be booleans.. but there is no option. [image]

I also want to add some fields as String with only drop down options, e.g. [image] [image] - again i can't find an option or anything online to help!

Comment: I don't think that shapefile can have a strict boolean field (but a numeric or text field restricted to two value like 0/1 or true/false can act as one). For your second question you should give more detail : do you want to always have the same option on the dropdown list ? does the added text field has always the same name and length ?...

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Yes i want to there to always be the same options in the drop drop down fields, so when people are out on site then can only select one of the 3 options. Sorry i some how miss a critical line when this posted, i want to do this model designer. But i don't believe it can be done.

I have figured out a workaround by creating a template and export it as a layer_file then this can be joined.